# Oracle number to char leading 0

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a function that calculates number of days
select (x * 0,5) from dual.
my problem is tha when x=1 i get .5 instead of 0,5.What i want to get is numbers in format 0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5 ..
Could you please give me a help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
select TO_CHAR(x * 0,5, '990,99') from dual
```

**EDIT:**

Try to create a function like this:

```
create function getDecimalFormat(x in number) 
    return varchar2
as
begin
    return RTRIM(TO_CHAR(x, 'FM999999999999990.99'), '.');
end;
```

Comment: select TO_CHAR(2*0.5, '990.99') from dual gives me 1.00 but i want 1

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but I did the following, where x is datatype NUMBER(20,3)

```
CASE WHEN x < 1 THEN '0'
  ELSE '' END
  || to_char(x)
```

I didn't want any trailing zeros but did want a leading zero if x was, say, 0.99 or 0.5

So I'm just using the regular to_char and adding a leading zero if x is less than 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you always want 1 decimal place use to_char to round

```
select TO_CHAR(28.324, '90.9') from dual;
```

returns

```
28.3
```

and

```
select TO_CHAR(28, '90.9') from dual;
```

returns

```
28.0
```

Hope this helps